# GraphQL Golang Authentication with JWT

Tags: go, authentication, graphql, jwt

I have a GraphQL API that I've been writing in `go` and wondering how to manage JWT authentication when you already are using `context` to pass around data sources.

So an abbreviated version of my `main` function is:

```golang
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/graphql-go/graphql"
    gqlhandler "github.com/graphql-go/handler"
)

func queryHandler(ds *sources.DataSources, gql *gqlhandler.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), sources.CtxSourcesKey, ds)
        gql.ContextHandler(ctx, w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    apiSchema, _ := schema.CompileSchema(schema.QueryType, schema.MutationType)
    gql := gqlhandler.New(&gqlhandler.Config{
        Schema:     &apiSchema,
        GraphiQL:   !isDeployed,
        Pretty:     false,
        Playground: false,
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":41000", util.CreateChiRouter(healthCheckHandler(), queryHandler(ctxSources, gql)))
}
```

As you can see, I'm already creating a new `context` instance to store and pass a map of my various data sources to the query resolution functions, but also need to be able to parse out the `Authorization` header for a possible JWT to be passed down for authenticated routes.

What's the best way to go about this given my current situation? (Combine the JWT with the data sources context? Handle data sources differently to free up `context`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of dealing with such authentication headers is to use a middleware to deal with authentication, and add the authentication info to the current context.

Currently, you're creating a new context. I suggest using the existing HTTP context and adding to that, so you can chain things:

```
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), sources.CtxSourcesKey, ds)
newReq:=r.WithContext(ctx)
gql.ContextHandler(ctx, w, newReq)
```

And you can install a middleware that does the same:

```
type autoInfoKeyType int

const authInfoKey authInfoKeyType=iota

func GetAuthInfo(ctx context.Context) *AuthInfo {
   if v:=ctx.Value(authInfoKey); v!=nil {
     return v.(*AuthInfo)
   }
   return nil
}

func AuthMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    authInfo:=processJWT(...)
    if authInfo!=nil {
       ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), authInfoKey, authInfo)
       r=r.WithContext(ctx)
    }
    next.ServeHTTP(w,r)
  }
}
```

This way, you can check if the context has authentication info, and if so, use it.

```
if authInfo:=GetAuthInfo(req.Context()); authInfo!=nil {
  ...
}
```

Comment: From your first snippet, what is the key that the incoming request context is add under? (i.e. how is it accessible?)

Comment: Are you talking about the `authInfoKey`? The `sources.CtxSourcesKey` is from your question

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn't very clear. Where does the value for `authInfoKey` come from?

Comment: oh nevermind, I was misread that. So then is this combining the two contexts into a single one to be passed?

Comment: Added some more code to show an implementation for `authInfoKey`. This uses the context in HTTP request all the way through, it does not create a new context.